# Shared lazy loaded component in Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm using Angular 8 with Ionic 4 and moving from Ionic 3 the lazy loading changed a bit.

I have a page which has another page (same route) inside of it and a component inside this last page. This component can be used on different pages/components.

So on my `app-routing.module.ts` I have something like this:

```
{
    path: 'welcome',
    data: {
      preload: true
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './pages/welcome/welcome.module#WelcomePageModule'
      }
    ]
  },
```

Pretty simple because as I said this route doesn't change, but why I need to have this as well inside `welcome.module.ts`?

```
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CreateAccountPageModule, <--- this is the other page inside (it's a completely different page from other link so I reuse it here)
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: WelcomePage
      }
    ])
    // IonicPageModule.forChild(WelcomePage)
  ],
```

Do I need here `RouterModule`? If I need to update my path, would I have to modify both files?

And for the component I need to load inside `CreateAccountPage`, how should I load it? I tried with above approach, loading `MyComponentModule` inside `CreateAccountPageModule`, but didn't work:

> Template parse errors: 'my-component' is not a known element

Comment: can you put together a stackblitz?

Comment: It's more a matter of understanding how lazy loading works with Angular 8/Ionic 4 than fixing any error tbh

Comment: @Dani are you trying to make any share module which you can use in multiple modules

Comment: no, just a single one. I posted an answer. Working fine now

Comment: not clear about `RouterModule.forChild([` tho. Would I need to modify both paths? (there and insider router.module)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it another way round maybe.

Two important things to be noted while calling components using selector

1. Both parent and child component must be declared in a module. In your case CreateAccountPage is parent component and MyComponentComponent is the child component.

   `declarations: [CreateAccountPage]`
2. If the child is declared in a different module other than parent, then this module must be imported in the parent.

   `imports: [BrowserModule]`

So I guess you should be probably importing the child's module in the parent module's import attribute like this :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CreateAccountPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, MyComponentModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [CreateAccountPage]
})
export class CreateAccountPageModule { }
```

Comment: I added `BrowserModule` because that was the only missing thing there but I cannot see any difference

Comment: I get rid of the error removing `BrowserModule` (because it was already loaded from first page) and importing `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` on `CreateAccountPageModule` but it doesn't display the content of `MyComponent`

Comment: In fact now I don't get any error even having `<component-that-does-not-exist />` on the html with `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA`

Answer (score 0):

Basically we have 2 different kinds of lazy loading from Angular 8:

### **With routing:**

Inside `app-routing.module.ts` we can find something like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'test',
    children: [ // we can use loadChildren directly but this is just to demonstrate that we could have child routes as well
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./pages/test/test.module').then(
            m => m.TestPageModule
          )
      },
      {
        path: 'my-test',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./pages/my-test/my-test.module').then(
            m => m.MyTestPageModule
          )
      }
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'something' }
];
```

This means that we have 2 pages with 2 routes lazy loaded:

- `/test`
- `/test/my-test`

NOTE: See that `my-test` is inside `test`, but we could move it outside for 2 totally different pages

### **Without routing:**

This is the classic way to lazy load a component. Inside the component create a `my-test.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MyTestComponent } from './my-test.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyTestComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  exports: [MyTestComponent]
})
export class MyTestComponentModule {}
```

Now, the only thing we have to do is import this module on the pages/components we want to display it. So if we want to display `MyTestComponent` inside `TestPage` we'll go to `test.module.ts` and we'll add this import:
`import: [MyTestComponentModule]` and use it like so:
`<app-my-text></app-my-test>`

NOTE: notice the `app` before your component name. This is automatically added by Angular CLI when you create the component from the terminal

---

- For Angular mayor versions updates I recommend this guide: https://update.angular.io/#5.2:8.0
- Interesting reading: https://www.joshmorony.com/using-angular-routing-with-ionic-4/